# Google app engine: filter by ID

Tags: python

I am lost somehow, I want to do something like below which filter by the ID.

```
id = 1000
query = Customers.all()
query.filter('ID =', id)
```

or

```
query = db.GqlQuery("select * from Customers where ID = %s" % id)
```

What is the correct method to filter by ID?

Answer (score 4):

both are correct and even Customers.gql("WHERE ID = :1", id);

Edit: If ID is the automatically created id property you should use Customers.get_by_id()

Comment: I tried that but all return no result, so I wonder what is the correct syntax of ID?

Comment: Do I need to write something into index.yaml to make this get_by_id function work with the default id?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `Customers.get_by_id(id)`

Comment: Do I need to set up index.yaml to make this function work with the default id?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and it turned out that I was just working too hard.  The answer lies in getObjectById().  If this works for you, please go to [my very-similar S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764300/on-google-app-engine-gae-how-do-i-search-on-the-key-id-field) and give Gordon's answer a vote-up, since he's the one who showed me this.

```
Player result = null;
if (playerKey == null)
{
    log.log(Level.WARNING, "Tried to find player with null key.");
}
else
{
    PersistenceManager pm = assassin.PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try {
        result = (Player) pm.getObjectById(Player.class, playerKey);
    } catch (javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException notFound) {
        // Player not found; we will return null.
        result = null;
    }

    pm.close();
}

return result;
```

Comment: Heh.  Oops, sorry -- I just noticed that you wanted python and I gave you Java.  Well, I'm sure there is a getObjectByID method in the python APIs, too.  Good luck!